# Python code for telnetting DUT needs further optimization

Tags: python-3.x

I need to further optimize my code in Python.

I was earlier executing commands on the Device Under Test step by step which was a lot as I also required sleep timers. However I was able to minimize it through a list and calling elements of the list in a for loop:

I need your inputs to further optimize this code:

```
ConfigListBFD = ['conf t' , 'int Fa1/0' , 'ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0', 'no shut']

for i in ConfigListBFD:
    tn.write(i.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    print (i, "command entered successfully")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Please note: I am telnetting the DUT as ssh is not supported.

Comment: What optimisations are you after? If it needs to run particularly quickly or efficiently, would C or C++ be better?

Comment: Can't you synchronize with `tn.read_until` instead of sleeping?

Answer (score 0):

i am using this optimized common code for telnet. we can create a common file where you can add this method

```
import telnetlib
import time

def telnet(host):
    user = <username>
    password = <password>
    try :
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    except :
        print("Unable to connect")
        sys.exit()
    tn.read_until(b"Username:") # read until username prompt 
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    if password:
        tn.read_until(b"password:") #read until password prompt
        tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.read_until(b"#")

    return tn   #return telnetlib handle
```

than import this method to another file, where we write our script